# Is it possible to unlock MS access database field with if sentence?

Tags: database, ms-access, field

For example i have 3 fields in one table. Auto numbering ID, name, surname. And I want to unlock surname field only then when name is Jack. Is it possible in MS ACCESS 2013?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible directly in the table. You should use a form, and lock / unlock the field(s) using VBA

Comment: Thanks for response. Maybe you could share a code how it looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You create the form.
2. You create two textboxes. Create three textboxes if you also want to show the auto field.
3. You lock/disable all other textboxes other than surname by default.
4. On the Change_event of the surname textbox you use the following code:

.

```
Sub txtSurname_Change()
  if (Me.txtsurname = "Jack") then
    Me.txtSurname.enable = True
    Me.txtSurname.Locked = False      
 Else
    Me.txtSurname.enable = False
    Me.txtSurname.Locked = True
 End if

End Sub
```

Here it will continously check if what the user typed is Jack. It would be wise to also add code to disable the textboxes again if it is not Jack anymore.